# Wordpress database access in mobile applications

Tags: iphone, database, android, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and I want to create an interface for being able to access my database hosted on wordpress in my mobile applications - particularly iPhone and Android.

As these do not directly access SQL databases and would need routines on the server-side for being able to do so, what would be the best way for me to go about writing these routines/web-service calls?

Are there any wordpress plugins available for this? If not, what language should I use - php or something else?

I need some lead.

Comment: See related question http://wordpress.org/support/topic/269173

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you do not need to access the database directly?

Wordpress supports the XML-RPC standard interface so applications can communicate with WP across the internet, without needing access to WP's database. http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support

If you choose to implement your apps' using XML-RPC, all your communication will be reduced to simple HTTP calls.

To get started I suggest checking out the *source code* of Wordpress' own iPhone application, which utilizes XML-RPC http://iphone.wordpress.org/

Also, note that Wordpress has published an extension to the XML-RPC API that includes WP specific functions: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a webapp (iPhone style) for the phone application and calling everything with AJAX to a PHP (Due to Wordpress running PHP) backend to validate and execute the queries. [iPhone webapps dev link](https://developer.apple.com/safari/mobile.php) I haven't found any solid tutorial/resource for developing BlackBerry webapps (Please post back if you find one)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new app, or trying to port the database, check out [WP Touch](http://www.bravenewcode.com/wptouch/), which is a Wordpress plugin/theme which will turn your wordpress install into an iPhone friendly site on iPhones.